# Is there a way to automatically encode attribute in where clause so it matches model setter (sequelize)?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have an API which retrieves all comments belonging to a user. I want to return only encrypted ids in my API. I have a getter which encodes comment id. Here is my model :

```
const Comment = sequelize.define('comment', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        field: 'id',
        get:encodeId, //function which encrypts id 
        set:decodeId //function which decrypts id
    },
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'user_id'
    })
```

When doing

```
Comment.findAll({where: {userId}}) ,
```

the id is being encrypted which is great.
My issue is if I want to look for the owner of a comment given an  encrypted comment id. 
For exemple, given id 123456, its encryption is "P1lY9052Oam". When doing

```
Comment.findAll({where: { id:"P1lY9052Oam"}})
```

I receive the following error: ***SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for integer: "P1lY9052Oam"***.
I would like to know if there is a way in sequelize to convert where attributes. Here I would like id to be converted by the decodeId function which is the id setter.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a static function on your Comment model

for example:

```
const Comment = sequelize.define('comment', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        field: 'id',
        get:encodeId, //function which encrypts id 
        set:decodeId //function which decrypts id
    },
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'user_id'
    })  

Comment.commentsByUserEncodeedId = function(id){
   // "decodeId" is your decode function
    return Comment.findAll({where: { id: decodeId(id) }});
}
```

```
// calling the function
Comment.commentsByUserEncodeedId("P1lY9052Oam")
        .then(function(results){
            console.log(results)
         });
```